# Resource Reservation Protocol (RSVP) utilization in Cisco

Tags: cisco, rsvp

I was trying to research how RSVP is utilized, and if it succeeded. I have the following question:

I notice Cisco routers do support RSVP, but is it really utilized, or is it just for few high-end, sophisticated apps?

Comment: The questions dealing with the PC OSes and applications are off-topic. You can ask these questions on Super User.

Comment: but it's related to Networking ....

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out if RSVP is popular across all those platforms including Cisco routers.

Comment: Questions about these sorts of things are off-topic. Please see the Help Center for which topics are allowed and which topics are not allowed. The place to ask question about OS and applications is Super User.

Comment: Ok ... Than at least they could answer the question related to Cisco.

Comment: Cisco routers support RSVP, but you came to that on you own. You don't have a question specific to Cisco; your question about Cisco relates to OS and applications on the PCs.

Comment: OK ... I will edit the questions and I will only focus on Cisco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco routers can be configured to support RSVP. RSVP would need to be configured on all the routers in a path from one endpoint to the other endpoint. This Cisco document may be useful to you: [Configuring RSVP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfrsvp.html), or you can search the Internet for "Cisco RSVP".

Once RSVP is properly configured on the routers, it is completely up to the applications and OSes on the endpoints as to whether or not it is used. This is beyond the scope of this site.